# oracle : Case : I/Elsef Query

Tags: oracle

I am executing a select statement as below

```
Select case 
         when count(*) = 0 then 'Pass' 
       end as Test_Result
  from Table Name 
 where condition;
```

I want output as below

```
If count(*)=0 then Result should be 'Pass'
```

Else I want the output of this query . I mean output of below one

```
Select Count(*)
  from Table Name 
 where condition;
```

Comment: Please understand that each the result of a SQL SELECT statement is a table and that the number of columns and their type is derived statically, i.e. just be looking at the SQL statement and the table definitions but without retrieving any table data. So what columns (incl. type) should your result have (so it fits both cases)?

Answer (score 3):

One option here is to execute the query with no `WHERE` condition and then use conditional aggregation to get the count which appears in the `ELSE` condition.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'Pass'
            ELSE CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR2(30))
       END AS Test_Result
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be :

**setup:**

```
create table emptyTab ( a number);
create table notEmptyTab ( a) as ( select 1 from dual );
```

This should do the trick:

```
SQL> select case
  2           when count(*) = 0 then 'Pass'
  3           else to_char(count(*))
  4         end
  5  from emptyTab
  6  where a = 1       ;

CASEWHENCOUNT(*)=0THEN'PASS'ELSETO_CHAR(
----------------------------------------
Pass

SQL> select case
  2           when count(*) = 0 then 'Pass'
  3           else to_char(count(*))
  4         end
  5  from notEmptyTab
  6  where a = 1;

CASEWHENCOUNT(*)=0THEN'PASS'ELSETO_CHAR(
----------------------------------------
1

SQL> select case
  2           when count(*) = 0 then 'Pass'
  3           else to_char(count(*))
  4         end
  5  from notEmptyTab
  6  where a = 2;

CASEWHENCOUNT(*)=0THEN'PASS'ELSETO_CHAR(
----------------------------------------
Pass
```

Comment: What If I have to fetch whole query result in else condition (Select * from Table)

Comment: Please answer :::What If I have to fetch whole query result in else condition (Select * from Table)

Comment: You can not.'Pass' is a single string, while the whole content of a table may be many columns with different types and you can not build a single query returning a variable number of columns